# Mistake in jqplot Line Chart

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jqplot

I have this piece of  code . I have no clue of why the chart is not being displayed.As the console shows it is being drawn but i am unable to display it.
I believe i have added the container but don't where this is going wrong.The console doesn't show any mistakes .

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile- 

 1.4.2.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>




</head>
<body>

<div data-role="tabs">
  <div data-role="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#one" data-theme="a" data-ajax="false">Price Grid</a></li>
      <li><a href="#two" data-theme="a" data-ajax="false">Price Chart</a></li>

    </ul>
</div>


    <div id="one" class="ui-content">

    <style>
         table,th,td
           {
             border:1px solid black;

           }
           th
             {
              background-color:green;
              color:white;
             }
       </style>



       <table id="myTable">


       </table>



    </div>

 <div id="two" style="height:400px;width:300px; "></div>

  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../js/jqplot/jquery.min.js">

     </script>
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" 
      src="../js/jqplot/jquery.jqplot.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../js/jqplot/jquery.jqplot.css" />

  <script type="text/javascript">

  $(function(){

  $.jqplot('two', [[[1, 2],[3,5.12],[5,13.1],[7,33.6],[9,85.9],[11,219.9]]]);

 });
</script>



</div>




    </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First include the bloody framework, how do you expect it will work when **jqplot** links are not correct.
Second set **display: block !important;**  to your div container **#two** .

#### Working example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div data-role="tabs">
  <div data-role="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#one" data-theme="a" data-ajax="false">Price Grid</a></li>
      <li><a href="#two" data-theme="a" data-ajax="false">Price Chart</a></li>

    </ul>
</div>

    <div id="one" class="ui-content">

    <style>
         table,th,td
           {
             border:1px solid black;

           }
           th
             {
              background-color:green;
              color:white;
             }
             
             #two {
                height:400px;
                width:300px;
                display: block !important; 
             }
       </style>



       <table id="myTable">


       </table>



    </div>

 <div id="two" style=""></div>

  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://www.jqplot.com/src/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://www.jqplot.com/src/jquery.jqplot.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.jqplot.com/src/jquery.jqplot.min.css" />

  <script type="text/javascript">

  $(function(){

  $.jqplot('two', [[[1, 2],[3,5.12],[5,13.1],[7,33.6],[9,85.9],[11,219.9]]]);

 });
</script>



</div>




    </body>
  </html>
```